# Wrong effective-pom output

Tags: maven

When calling help:effective-pom in some child modules position, the output prints wrong path.

Some url like `.../${groupId}/${some_other_sibling's_artifactId}/...`

This is also making site deploy wrong.

Can anybody help?

Comment: May be you can give more details like a error message output ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use ${project.groupId} instead of {groupId}